# how to use the splited data of my datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a date picker that work perfectly but I need the date split. The normal output is `12/16/1900`. I need to split this into `month = 12, day = 16 and year = 1900`. I already made this but I don't know how to use them in a function. It throws undefined when I use them on a function.

This is how it was split:

```
const [month, day, year] = vBirthDate.split('/')
console.log(`Month: ${month}`)
console.log(`Day: ${day}`)
console.log(`Year: ${year}`)
```

This works very good, it prints the correct month, day and year.

This is my code

```
    import DatePicker from 'react-native-datepicker';
const PersonalForm = ({onSubmit, errorMessage}) => {
    const [vBirthDate, setvBirthDate] = useState('');
    const [month, day, year] = vBirthDate.split('/')
    console.log(`Month: ${month}`)
   console.log(`Day: ${day}`)
   console.log(`Year: ${year}`)

    const RFC = () => {
        console.log(vName, 
        vSecondName, 
        vLastName, 
        vSecondLastName, 
        vBirthDate,
        vBirthDate.day,
        `Month: ${month}`, `Day: ${day}`, `Year: ${year}`);
    }
         return ( 
        <ScrollView>

        <View style={styles.containerdate}>
                <DatePicker 
                  date={vBirthDate} //initial date from state
                  mode="date" //The enum of date, datetime and time
                  placeholder="select date"
                  format="DD/MM/YYYY"
                  minDate="01/01/1900"
                  maxDate="01/01/2019"
                  confirmBtnText="Confirm"
                  cancelBtnText="Cancel"
                  androidMode="spinner"
                  customStyles={{
                    placeholderText: {
                      fontSize: 16,
                    },
                    dateIcon: {
                      height: 0,
                      width: 0,
                    },
                    dateText: {
                      color: '#b3b4b5',
                      fontSize: 16,
                    },
                    dateInput: {
                      borderWidth: 0,
                    }
                  }}
                  onDateChange={(date) => {setvBirthDate(date);RFC();} }
                />
              </View>
        </ScrollView>
    );
};
```

on my RFC function everything prints fine but the dates. I tried 3 different ways to print any of the dates but none of them work (they return undefined).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `vBirthDate,month` in function should be `vBirthDate.month`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually very close. Look at this:

```
const vBirthDate = '12/16/1900';
const RFC = () => {
  const [month, day, year] = vBirthDate.split('/');
  console.log(vName, 
    vSecondName, 
    vLastName, 
    vSecondLastName, 
    vBirthDate,
    `Month: ${month}`, `Day: ${day}`, `Year: ${year}`);
}
```

The issue in your code is that you are treating `vBirthDate` as an object which in fact is a string. The `.split()` creates an array so the elements are accessible via index numbers (or array destructuring), not via `.` (dot) operator.

Comment: this stil throw me undefined

Comment: What exactly throws undefined? Can you show more code? Currently it's hard to tell more

Comment: added the whole code, the console .log prints undefined